# How to Call API in a Loop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, pokeapi

I have a list of Pokemon names that I am looping through and using to call the PokeApi. Then, I want to take the returned data and output a simple display.

I am encountering issues saving the data and returning it, but I don't know where I'm going wrong.
My output never has all of the pokemon that I would expect it to have and the return values are inconsistent with previous ones. So there might be issues with data being overwritten or synchronicity, but none of my attempts to fix it have worked.

Here's the code:

App.tsx

```
import { gen1List } from 'data';
import React from 'react';
import { Pokemon } from 'models';
import { useFetchPokemon } from 'api/useFetchPokemon';

export const App = () => {
    const gen1Pokemon = useFetchPokemon(gen1List);

    return (
        <>
            {gen1Pokemon.map((pokemon: Pokemon, index: number) => (
                <div key={index}>
                    {pokemon.name}
                    <img src={pokemon.sprite} alt={pokemon.name} />
                </div>
            ))}
        </>
    );
};
```

useFetchPokemon.ts

```
import { Pokemon, filterPokemonData } from "models";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { fetchPokemon } from "api/fetchPokemon";

export const useFetchPokemon = (pokemonList: string[]) => {
    const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState<Pokemon[]>([]);
    const pokemonArray: Pokemon[] = [];

    useEffect(() => {
        for (const mon of pokemonList) {
            fetchPokemon(mon).then((result) => {
                pokemonArray.push(filterPokemonData(result));
            });
        };

        setPokemon(pokemonArray);
    }, []);

    return pokemon;
};
```

fetchPokemon.ts

```
export const fetchPokemon = async (name: string): Promise<any> => {
    const response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + name);
    return await response.json();
};
```

models.ts

```
export interface Pokemon {
    name: string;
    sprite: string;
};

export const filterPokemonData = (pokemon): Pokemon => {
    return {
        name: pokemon.name,
        sprite: pokemon.sprites.front_default,
    }
};
```

data.ts

```
export const gen1List: string[] = [
    'bulbasaur',
    'venusaur',
    'charizard',
];
```

I've tried making the call a lot of different ways, with or without a hook. I've experimented with using useCallback, putting the loop in its own async function and calling that, setting the state inside the loop, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the code more efficient and easy to understand, you can use `Promise.all` to fetch data for all the Pokémon simultaneously and then update the state when all the promises have resolved. Here's an updated version of your custom hook:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { fetchPokemon } from "api/fetchPokemon";

export const useFetchPokemon = (pokemonList: string[]) => {
    const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState<Array<Pokemon>>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const promises = pokemonList.map((mon) => fetchPokemon(mon));
                const pokemonData = await Promise.all(promises);
                const filteredPokemon = pokemonData.map(filterPokemonData);
                setPokemon(filteredPokemon);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching Pokémon:", error);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [pokemonList]);

    return pokemon;
};
```

In this updated code:

1. We use `Promise.all` to fetch Pokémon data for all the items in the `pokemonList` array concurrently, which should be faster than making sequential requests.
2. We handle any errors that might occur during the data fetching process and log them to the console.
3. The custom hook now takes the `pokemonList` array as a dependency for the `useEffect`, ensuring that it will re-run whenever `pokemonList` changes.
4. We simplify the code by directly setting the `filteredPokemon` array in the `setPokemon` function. This avoids the need for an intermediate `pokemonArray` variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The code worked perfectly and your explanations were clear and instructive.